# resetting counters in LaTeX

Tags: numbering

I have used

```
\section*{\centerline{3. abc}} 
\setcounter{section}{3}
```

command. It sets section heading in the centre of the page. But my first definition of 3rd section is being numbered as 3.8 instead of 3.1. Last dfinition of section 2 is numbered as 2.7. I want to reset the counters of definitions, theorems, examples for each section. How shuold i proceed? Please help!!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE

Comment: don't do this! `\section*{\centerline{3. abc}} ` that is an unnumbered section (so does not reset the subsection counter) even though it will appear to the reader like a numbered section. You should not have formatting in that argument, use `\section{abc}`

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't do `\setcounter{section}{3}\section{\centerline{abc}}`?

Comment: @DLichti Shouldn't it be `\setcounter{section}{2}\section...`  then? (`\section` does increment the counter...)

Comment: @UlrichDiez Sure, my main point was reversing `\setcounter` and `\section`.

Comment: Be aware that with "starred sectioning commands" like `\section*` the actions which are needed for the `\label..\ref`-mechanism to work (and in case of using the hyperref-package, the hyperlink-mechanism and the bookmark-mechanism to work) are **not** performed. Running heads of pages where section titles are to appear might as well be a problem with starred sectioning commands. Also counters which in the sectioning hierarchy are subordinated  are not reset to 0 with starred sectioning commands. The packages **titlesec** and **titletoc** might be of interest to you.

Comment: Each counter has associated a macro `\cl@<counter>` for resetting to 0 the counter which in the sectioning hierarchy is subordinated to it. In your case you can do something like `\section*{\centerline{3. abc}} \setcounter{section}{2}\refstepcounter{section}{\makeatletter\let\@elt\@stpelt\cl@section\makeatother}`.   (The `\refstepcounter`-thingie makes it possible to use `\label..\ref` inside the starred section.) If using hyperref, the anchor will not be at "3" but behind "c".

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're engaging in quite a bit of low-level, "visual" formatting of your document. Now this is precisely what LaTeX is supposed to make unnecessary. The following, really old joke comes to mind: "Good Fortran programmers can program in Fortran in any language."

E.g., by issuing the instruction

```
\section*{\centerline{3. abc}}
```

to (a) center-set the sectioning header (here: "abc") while (b) placing a "dot" (aka "full stop") after the (c) manually-set section number, all the while using `\section*`, you engage in three distinct manual low-level formatting operations. As you must be aware, `\section*` does *not increment* the counter called `section`. And then you're surprised that the next definition's counter shows "3.8" rather than "3.1".

You will find writing documents in LaTeX far more enjoyable -- and you'll certainly be a lot more productive -- if you make a habit of distinguishing between low-level formatting-related matters (which, ideally, should be dealt with in the document's preamble) and matters of content and high-level, structural instructions, which is what the body of the document should be about.

E.g., something like the following might be useful for you.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

%% 1. define a 'defn' environment
\usepackage{amsthm} % or 'ntheorem'
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section] % subordinate 'defn' counter to 'section' counter

%% 2. place a dot after section number in section header
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
   {\csname the#1\endcsname\space}%    default
   {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}}%  enable individual control
\def\section@cntformat{\thesection.\space} % section-level
\makeatother

%% 3. center-set section-level headers
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\centering}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{2} % just for this example
\setcounter{defn}{7}

\begin{defn} \dots \end{defn}

\section{abc}
\begin{defn} \dots \end{defn}

\end{document}
```